# Marionette onAttach lifecycle not fired during testing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I am writing tests in which I have some logic inside the onAttach lifecycle method, but when testing the onAttach is never called.

This is how I initially tried to test it

```
 beforeEach(() => {
        view = new OffersTab();
        view.render();
 });
```

but my understanding was that it onAttach gets fired when region is shown, so then i attempted to do it this way,

```
beforeEach(() => {
    let parentView = new AllOffers();
    parentView.render();
    parentView.getRegion('offersTab').show(new OffersTab());

    view = parentView.getRegion('offersTab');
});
```

But still the onAttach is not firing, leaving me unable to write tests

Comment: Did you check if it actually got attached to DOM? Maybe it didn't find right selectors in test

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the [`attach` event](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.2.0/viewlifecycle.html#view-attach) on a view and the [`show` event](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.2.0/viewlifecycle.html#region-show) on a region. (The `onAttach` method is a convenience method that does not need subscribing by `listenTo`.)

### Attach

The `attach` event is triggered when your view is shown in a region *and this gets the view attached to the DOM* - to an element that has its ancestor in the page's `document` (`document.documentElement`). It means that either the view's element (`el`) or the parent view's or an ancestor view's has been appended to the DOM. It is not enough to show the view in a parent view's region. First when that parent view is appended to DOM, the event will be triggered recursively down to all child views.

You can check it by testing `parentView`, before you show the child view in there:

```js
// All will return false
document.documentElement.contains(parentView.el);
Marionette.isNodeAttached(parentView.el);
parentView.isAttached();
```

If your view needs to be appended to DOM to work properly, you have to pick an element which is in the DOM and show the parent view in it. For example, in `document.body`:

```js
let body, parentView, view;

before(() => { // mocha's "before all"
  body = new Marionette.Region({ el: 'body' });
});

beforeEach(() => {
  parentView = new AllOffers();
  body.show(parentView); // attach the parent view to DOM

  view = new OffersTab();
  parentView.getRegion('offersTab').show(view);
});

afterEach(() => {
  body.empty(); // detach and destroy the view
});
```

Alternatively, you could make the `AllOffers` attach to DOM itself it its code. Or pass an element in the DOM to its constructor, for example: `new AllOffers({ el: body })`. Don't remember to destroy it, when you don't need it.

### Show

When a view is shown in a region, the event `show` will triggered *on the region*, not on the view. (I write about Marionette 3 or newer. Marionette 2 triggered the `show` event on the view.)

If your event handler needs to be executed right after showing the view it in a parent view's region, but not after the view appears in DOM, consider moving your code to the [`render` event](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/marionette.view.html#view-render) (or `onRender` method). You could listen to the `show` event on the region and re-trigger it on your child view, but you'd better follow Marionette's best practices and [use other events](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/upgrade.html#show-and-beforeshow).